# Filter through checkboxes that were pulled from database and match results associated with the checkboxes

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, sequelize.js, handlebars.js

My project is a project idea generator page where a user is given a list of coding languages. I am using handlebars and javascript to render the page. Whichever languages they select, a list of projects that use those languages should show up on the page. I used sequelize and seeds to connect the language database and project database using a many to many relationship.

When I call on the database in my javascript, I am shown a list of languages and their associated project names.

I have no idea how to create this filtering checkbox system using the json data. This is what I have so far:

```js
// This is the data from my model seed. I am just including it here for reference:
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "language_name": "HTML/CSS",
        "project_id": null,
        "projects": [
            {
                "project_name": "Job Search Board",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "project_name": "Blank Project",
                "id": 2
            },
            {
                "project_name": "Project 3",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "project_name": "Example Project 4",
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "language_name": "Javascript",
        "project_id": null,
        "projects": [
            {
                "project_name": "Job Search Board",
                "id": 1
            },
            {
                "project_name": "Project 3",
                "id": 3
            },
            {
                "project_name": "Example Project 4",
                "id": 4
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "language_name": "Express",
        "project_id": null,
        "projects": [
            {
                "project_name": "Project 3",
                "id": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "language_name": "React",
        "project_id": null,
        "projects": []
    }
]

const filt=document.getElementById("filt"),
      list=document.querySelector("#list tbody");
let cols={}, trs; // arrays for columns sequence in data and all table records
      
// set up filtering (needs be done only once, before the AJAX call):
filt.addEventListener("change",ev=>{let cb=ev.target;
  let tst=Object.entries([...filt.querySelectorAll(":checked")].reduce((a,c)=>((a[c.name]=a[c.name]||[]).push(c.value),a), {}));
  trs.forEach(tr=>
   tr.style.display=tst.length==0 || tst.every(([n,arr])=>arr.includes(tr.children[cols[n]].textContent)) 
     ?"":"none"
  )
}); 

$.ajax({
  url: "/api/languages",
  method: "GET",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: 'projects',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.length) { // only if data array is not empty
      // columns sequence:
      Object.keys(data[0]).forEach((c,i)=>cols[c]=i);
      // build the filter-menu structure:
      const menu={language_name:{}};
            data.forEach(f=>Object.entries(menu).forEach(([k,o])=>o[f[k]]=1));
     
      // translate the filter-menu structure into HTML:
      filt.innerHTML=Object.entries(menu).map(([k,o])=>k+':<br>'+
        Object.keys(o).map(c=>'<label><input type="checkbox" value="'+c+'" name="'+k+'">'+c+'</label>').join('<br>')
      ).join('<br>\n');
     
      // fill the main project list with data entries:
      list.innerHTML=data.map(f=>'<tr><td>'+Object.values(f).join('</td><td>')+'</td></tr>').join('\n');
      trs=[...list.children];
     }
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="filt"></div>
<div id="list"><table><thead><tr><th>Project</th></thead>
<tbody></tbody></table</tdiv>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/projecttwo.js"></script>
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think your question is specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the filtering problem by creating two functions to build the GUI. The first function `showFilters()` would build the list of languages which does not change. The second function `showProjects()` would build the list of projects. Then you just need to modify your change event handler to filter and update the projects section.

You can build a simple filter by getting a list of all the checked inputs and concatenating their values. Then you only need to use [String.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to filter the array using the `lanuage_name` field.

**The filter**

```
filt.addEventListener("change", ev => {
  let keywords = [...filt.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked")].map(p => p.value).join(",")

  let subset = data.filter(item => keywords.includes(item.language_name));

  showProjects(subset);

});
```

*keep in mind that there are many ways to build a filter and this is the most simple*

**HTML Templates**

Though it wasn't part of the question, the html isn't being generated correctly. This is why you see [object object] in the display. You may want to learn about JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) which can make this job easier.

**Update**

The snippet was updated to display the projects in a different format per OP's comments.

**Snippet**

Review and run the code snippet to understand how it works.

```js
const data = [{"id":1,"language_name":"HTML/CSS","project_id":null,"projects":[{"project_name":"Job Search Board","id":1},{"project_name":"Blank Project","id":2},{"project_name":"Project 3","id":3},{"project_name":"Example Project 4","id":4}]},{"id":2,"language_name":"Javascript","project_id":null,"projects":[{"project_name":"Job Search Board","id":1},{"project_name":"Project 3","id":3},{"project_name":"Example Project 4","id":4}]},{"id":3,"language_name":"Express","project_id":null,"projects":[{"project_name":"Project 3","id":3}]},{"id":4,"language_name":"React","project_id":null,"projects":[]}];


const filt = document.getElementById("filt"),
  list = document.querySelector("#list tbody");
let cols = {},
  trs;

function showFilter(data) {

  if (!data.length) return;

  Object.keys(data[0]).forEach((c, i) => cols[c] = i);
  const menu = {
    language_name: {}
  };
  data.forEach(f => Object.entries(menu).forEach(([k, o]) => o[f[k]] = 1));
  filt.innerHTML = Object.entries(menu).map(([k, o]) => k + ':<br>' +
    Object.keys(o).map(c =>
      '<label><input type="checkbox" value="' + c + '" name="' + k + '">' + c + '</label>').join(''));

  showProjects(data);

}

function showProjects(data) {

    // create an array of all the projects
    let projects = data.reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b.projects), [])
    
    // sort the array by project id 
    .sort((a,b) => a.id - b.id)
    
    // remove duplicates projects by comparing current and previous id
    .filter((item, index, array) => !index || item.id !== array[index-1].id);

    // update table
    list.innerHTML = projects.length > 0 
      ? projects.map(item => `<tr><td>${item.id}</td><td>${item.project_name}</td></tr>`).join("\n")
      : `<tr><td colspan="10">No matching projects found</td</tr>`;
      
  trs = [...list.children];
}

filt.addEventListener("change", ev => {
  let keywords = [...filt.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:checked")].map(p => p.value).join(",")

  let subset = data.filter(item => keywords.includes(item.language_name));

  showProjects(subset);

});


showFilter(data);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
label {
  margin-right: 2rem;
}

table {
  margin-top: 1em;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table td {
  padding: 0.2rem;
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
}
table th {
  background-color: steelblue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="filt"></div>
<div id="list">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr><th>ID</th><th>Projects</th></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! What exactly would I have to fix here for it to not display it as [object, Object]?

Comment: I've update the snippet to use template literals to build the project html and display the list of project names. If you need other fields you can easily add them based on the example.

Comment: sorry again, but instead of having the projects repeat everytime a language is checked, is there a way to only show the projects once? for instance, if one project has both javascript and react, and when the user selects both, it only shows the project once? not twice like in the table.

Comment: @manggae - I've updated the snippet to display a unique list of projects. See the comments in the showProjects() function for details.